# Command \labelindent already defined

Tags: enumitem, ieeetran

Using the [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/documents/windows_latex_template.zip) latex sample, whenever I add "enumitem" package as below

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  something
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
  Intro
\end{document}
```

I get this error

```
(c:/Program Files/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty
(c:/Program Files/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Command \labelindent already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.45 \newlength{\labelindent}

?
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Your MWE compile OK for me.  Maybe your packages are out of date.

Comment: No such problem here. Have you tried to delete your auxiliary files and recompile?

Comment: It looks like you have TeXLive2011 -- any chance you could update your TeX distribution to TeXLive2013?

Comment: I will try to update Texlive. Meanwhile, I see this post, but don't understand what should I do http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/68652

Comment: From [the ctan repository](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/), in the file IEEEtrans.cls, line 4903, the lines mentioned in the post you refer got commented in the current release. Your version of IEEEtran.cls probably has the line uncommented.

Comment: the cls file from ctan differs from the same file in IEEE package. I see that the line `\let\labelindent\IEEElabelindent` is uncommented in my IEEEtrans.cls

Answer (score 36):

I just experienced the same problem (with Texlive 2013 and the IEEE template V3). But actually [your linked post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/68652) pretty much says all you need to solve the problem. Since the `\labelindent` command exists for legacy reasons in the IEEE template, you can simply "disable" it by adding the following before importing the `enumitem` package:

```
\let\labelindent\relax
```